# Converting pixel position to geographical coordinates (lat, long) for a Sentinel-1 SAR image

Tags: python, geolocation, sentinel1, snap-python, sentinel2

How can i get the **geographical coordinates** from x,y position in a Sentinel-1 Synthetic Aperture Radar (SAR) satellite image?

For example, I can access a downloaded image info `sg` as

```
from snappy import ProductIO
from snappy import PixelPos 
path='path_name'
product = ProductIO.readProduct(path)
sg = product.getSceneGeoCoding()
```

But how can I get **latitude** and **longitude** for a desired point (x, y) in `sg` using [ESA's snap engine within Python](https://github.com/senbox-org/snap-engine/tree/master/snap-python/src/main/resources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the custom function below, we can easily convert any point inside our image `sg` to its coordinates (latitude,longitude):

```
def LatLon_from_XY(ProductSceneGeoCoding, x, y):
    #From x,y position in satellite image (SAR), get the Latitude and Longitude
    geopos = ProductSceneGeoCoding.getGeoPos(PixelPos(x, y), None)
    latitude = geopos.getLat()
    longitude = geopos.getLon()
    return latitude, longitude
```

UPD:
Because of various snap version updates, function above may not be working properly. Function below should work most of the times.

```
def LatLon_from_XY(product, x, y):
    geoPosType = jpy.get_type('org.esa.snap.core.datamodel.GeoPos')
    geocoding = product.getSceneGeoCoding()
    geo_pos = geocoding.getGeoPos(snappy.PixelPos(x, y), geoPosType())
    if str(geo_pos.lat)=='nan':
        raise ValueError('x, y pixel coordinates not in this product')
    else:
        return geo_pos.lat, geo_pos.lon
```

E.g. for the given `sg` product, we can get coordinates of pixel (x=12000, y=2000) as

```
latitude, longitude = LatLon_from_XY(sg, 12000, 2000)
```

Comment: I have installed the snappy package, but ProductIO or PixelPos, am i missing something ?

Comment: have you installed esa' s snappy?
https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/19300362/How+to+use+the+SNAP+API+from+Python#HowtousetheSNAPAPIfromPython-Configuration